# i have some files encrypted in gallery vault application

Tags: applications

I have some files encrypted in [gallery vault](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.galleryvault&hl=en) but my phone's software crashed and had to be reinstalled.

how can I restore my data from that app?

I do have my SD card but it is not showing my encrypted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [developers website](http://www.thinkyeah.com/myfaq/index.php?sid=320736&lang=en&action=artikel&cat=2&id=14&artlang=en) it *should* be as simple as copying the Gallery Vault backup data folder `.thinkyeah/` to your new device's SD card. You should then be able to install the app on your new device and open the vault with the same password you previously used.

Comment: thanx a lot for your quick and positive response :)

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?